# If 日本語する is not ok, why is 日本語できる ok?

Tags: verbs, potential-form

This is my understanding:

1. する名詞：

   > 運転する。
   >   残業する。
   >   勉強する。
2. their potential forms:

   > 運転することができる。
   >   残業することができる。
   >   勉強することができる。
3. abbreviated potential forms:

   > 運転できる。
   >   残業できる。
   >   勉強できる。

Can you say 日本語する?
If the answer is **no**, how can 日本語できる be grammatically correct?
Without realizing it, you are actually saying 日本語が分かることができます.

If ジョン**が**日本語できる is grammatically incorrect, why is it listed as the premier example of how to use **が** with the exhaustive listing meaning in this thread with 83 up-votes: [What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/22/whats-the-difference-between-wa-%E3%81%AF-and-ga-%E3%81%8C)

I read ジョン**が**日本語できる as ジョン**が**日本語**が**分かること**が**できる. But, now it looks like a sentence with 3 **が** that has 2 implied. That seems kind of deceptive and not that useful.

---

**Summary of the question**

I agree that ジョン**が**日本語できる sounds ok. It looks like a sentence with one が. But, you can only create that by tacitly implying **が**分かること**が**? 日本語 is not a サ変名詞. You can't say 日本語する. So, you can't simply say 日本語できる? There must be implied が?

83 up-votes cannot be wrong, so where am I wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Can you say "日本語する"?

I suppose you can use it idiomatically or somewhat playfully (perhaps akin to something like "I'm Japanese-ing it up"), but it's not a real verb that is used.

> If the answer is no, how can "日本語できる" be grammatically correct?
> Without realizing it, you are actually saying "日本語が分かることができます。".

日本語できる is really just dropping the `が` from 日本語***が***できる.  Whether or not simply leaving out particles in casual speech is grammatically correct or not is debatable (I would say it isn't).  Also, 分かる is a bit special in that it already includes potentiality in its own definition—"can understand"—so saying `日本語が分かることができます` is redundant at best.

So to answer the question, 日本語できる is acceptable because it's just particle-less casual speech, while 日本語する is something that is, at best, not used, and completely incorrect at worst.

> If "ジョンが日本語できる" is grammatically incorrect, why is it listed as the premier example of how to use が with the exhaustive listing meaning in this thread with 83 up-votes:
> What's the difference between wa (は) and ga (が)?

I suspect that due to the whole point of that thread being comparing and contrasting は and が, the author of that post intentionally left out the が between 日本語 and できる to avoid further confusion about が; but I'm no mind-reader.

Comment: I'm saying (1) "日本語が分かる" is perfect. If "日本語できる" is derived from "日本語が分かることができる" then "日本語できる" is also perfect / formal. (2) BUT, if "日本語できる" is derived from "日本語する", then "日本語できる" also sounds goofy / informal? To me, "日本語できる" sounded inappropriate for a grammatical discussion. btw:  another example sentence in that wa/ga thread, "「だれが日本語を知っていますか？」" sounds strange (wrong?). I'm sure one should say "日本語が理解できる" or "日本語が分かる".  "日本語を知る" sounds like a beginner mistake. But what do i know. I can't even pass JLPT2...

Comment: @David_W Why do you say 日本語できる is derived from 日本語する? できる and する are different verbs.

Comment: @Blavius "できる" is potential form of "する". Ok, so the only way you can place する next to a noun is if the noun is サ変名詞。So, how to make "日本語 + できる"? The catch-all サ変名詞 is "こと". Long story short, you place サ変名詞 into their potential forms like "残業することができる". Drop "することが" and that allows for "残業できる". Ok. So: "日本語" is a noun, but _not_ a サ変名詞。So, how to place "できる" next to "日本語"? Only option is to attach "日本語が分かる" to the catch-all サ変名詞,"こと". This leaves "日本語が分かることをする。". Change to potential form as such: "日本語が分かることができる". Drop "が分かることが", which leaves "日本語できる".

Answer (score 4):

The heart of your confusion lies in the fact that できる can serve in other roles in which it is not the potential form of する。It's better to think of 出来る as its own completely separate word, which also has a use/meaning that conveniently lets it fill the role of the potential form of する。

Let's look at the definition of できる・出来る in a dictionary (大辞林第2版).

> 1. 自然に生じる。（ア）それまでなかった物が生じる。
> 2. 新たに作られて完成する。
> 3. 作物が成熟する。また，作物が生長する。
> 4. 課せられた作業・課題や準備が完成・完了する。仕上がる。
> 5. 材質・つくりが…である。
> 6. 人が…するように生まれついている。教育されている。
> 7. 能力・人柄がすぐれている。
> 8. 世間に知られないうちに，男女が情交を結ぶような親しい仲になる。
> 9. 能力・可能性がある。近世以降の用法。
>    （ア）おこないうる。
>    （イ）それをうまく行える。
>    （ウ）動作性の名詞を受けて，…をすることが可能であるという意を表す。
>    （エ）サ変動詞の語幹に付いて，…することが可能であるの意を表す。

Only definition #9 is the potential form of する. Everything else encapsulates できる's unique meaning.

As @istrasci said, here 日本語できる is actually 日本語[が/は]できる abbreviated. This できる is NOT an abbreviation of 分かることができる (and as @istrasci mentioned, the meaning of stative/affective verbals like 分かる already encompasses their potential meaning). Also, the "hidden" が here is not the one in ジョン**が**日本語できる, but in something like ジョンが日本語**が**できる.

You are right that 日本語 is not a サ変名詞/compound verbal. If 日本語 could be used as such (i.e. 日本語する), then we would not have 日本語ができる, but just 日本語できる as the unabbreviated form.

I think using 大辞林 might not be the best dictionary to explore the 日本語ができる meaning of できる, though, so let's use 新明解（第五版）for that:

> 1.〈（なに・どこニ）―〉 物事が生じる。
>
> 2. 〈（なにニ）―〉 成立する。
> 3. その方面の特技を持っていたり それをこなすだけの能力を備えていたり する。
> 4. 何かをする△見込み（チャンス・余裕・権利）が有る。
> 5. その人のしようとした事が支障無く成立する。
> 6. 〔俗〕（相愛の）男女の間に、情交関係が成立する。

#3 is the definition we want. Zooming into the example sentences for #3, we see:

- 運転ができる
- **外国語のできる〔＝話せる〕人**
- この問題は私には出来ない
- よくできる〔＝成績の良い〕人だ

We can also see here how できる is different from 分かる, in that it implies that someone can speak the language, not merely understand it.

According to JSL (Japanese: The Spoken Language) by Jorden, this usage of できる means something akin to "capable:"

> **Sâtoo-san wa eégo ga dekimàsu.** 'Mr/s. Sato (for one) is capable in *English*."

-Lesson 5, p. 116 (the romanization is a kunrei variant; don't be alarmed by the oo/ee)